# How can I change inline style to css using Material-ui in React?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I am using inline styling to override the styling of material-UI components in React. Recently, I realized that using CSS is a more organized and better way to style components. I have referred all the documents on the material-ui user guides. But couldn't find the solution.

Working Code:

```
const useStyles = theme => ({
   input: {
     color: '#000',
     fontSize: "14px",
   },
});
```

Inside render method of Class.

```
const { classes } = this.props;

<TextField
    InputProps={{
      className: classes.input
    }}
    InputLabelProps={{
      className: classes.input
    }}

 />

export default withStyles(useStyles)(MyClass);
```

I want to override style using CSS like below:

CSS File:

```css
     .input {
        color: #ffffff;
         font-size: 18px;
      }
```

```
InputProps={{
          className: "input"
        }}
```

How can I achieve that? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a CSS file and normal className can override the styling of material-UI component, but the CSS specificity is important. According to the [Material-UI docs](https://material-ui.com/styles/advanced/#css-injection-order):

> By default, the style tags are injected last in the `<head>` element of the page. They gain more specificity than any other style tags on your page e.g. CSS modules, styled components.

The `StylesProvider` component has an `injectFirst` prop to inject the style tags first in the head(less priority).

```
import { StylesProvider } from '@material-ui/styles';

<StylesProvider injectFirst>
  {/* Your component tree.
      Styled components can override Material-UI's styles. */}
</StylesProvider>
```

Comment: Could you please give an example of where you write the css/scss in this declaration?